# Inequalities finding the set of solutions

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Find the set of solutions to this inequality?

$|x − 3| + |x − 6| < 5$

I have been taught to do it by treating $x$ in $3$ separate cases however I am not getting the correct answer. The answer is 'The set of real numbers $x$ such that $2 < x < 7.$ I am getting The set of real numbers $x$ such that $2 < x < 3$ or $6 < x < 7$.

Method

Case 1 $x<3$

$|x-3|= -(x-3)$

$|x-6|= -(x-6)$

$-(x-3)-(x-6)<5$

$-2x+9<5$

$-2x<-4$

$2x>4$

$x>2$

Because you have assumed $x<3$ the solutions is the intersection so $2<x<3$.

Case 2: $3<x<6$

$|x-3|= (x-3)$

$|x-6|= -(x-6)$

$(x-3)-(x-6)<5$

$3<5$

No solutions

Case 3: $x>6$

$|x-3|= (x-3)$

$|x-6|= (x-6)$

$(x-3)+(x-6)<5$

$2x-9<14$

$x<7$

Assumed $x>6$ therefore $6<x<7$.

So joint solutions the set of real numbers $x$ such that $2 < x < 3$ or $6 < x < 7$.

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Case 2:

3 < x < 6

|x-3|= (x-3)

|x-6|= -(x-6)

(x-3)-(x-6)<5

3<5

3<5 is true, so 3 < x < 6 is also solution for |x − 3| + |x − 6| < 5

Finally we have |x − 3| + |x − 6| < 5 $\Leftrightarrow$ 2 < x < 7